# Jquery - Hide elements on child hover, while showing on parent

Tags: jquery

What I've got is a table, which shows buttons with options while you hover on table row. I want to hide buttons, when you hover specific column (well, table cell to be exactly).

For now I'm trying to make something like this:

```
$('.f-t-row').on('hover', function(e){
        if(e.target.hasClass('block-checkbox')){
            if (e.type == "mouseenter") {
                $('.f-t-row').find('.table-ghost-buttons').hide(); 
            }
            else { // mouseleave
                $(this).find('.table-ghost-buttons').show(); 
            }
        }
        else {
            if (e.type == "mouseenter") {
                $(this).find('.table-ghost-buttons').show(); 
            }
            else { // mouseleave
                $('.f-t-row').find('.table-ghost-buttons').hide(); 
            }   
        }       
    });
```

But I don't know what's the problem, because I can't check event target class like that:

```
if(e.target.hasClass('block-checkbox'))
```

Console will always log something like this:

> Object # has no method 'hasClass'

You can see that here: http://jsfiddle.net/57aQP/

What's the possible way to fix that error and check if event target (which mouse hovers) got specific class?

Comment: why not use `$(this).` instead of `e.target`?  If you need to use e.target, then you need to make it into a jQuery object to use `hasClass`: `$(e.target)` - http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/57aQP/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `e.target` is not a jQuery object, you have to build it like `$(e.target)`, but is the same as `$(this)`.

Code:

```
$('.f-t-row').on('hover', function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).hasClass('block-checkbox')) {
        if (e.type == "mouseenter") {
            $('.f-t-row').find('.table-ghost-buttons').hide();
        } else { // mouseleave
            $(this).find('.table-ghost-buttons').show();
        }
    } else {
        if (e.type == "mouseenter") {
            $(this).find('.table-ghost-buttons').show();
        } else { // mouseleave
            $('.f-t-row').find('.table-ghost-buttons').hide();
        }
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/57aQP/1/